# Popping System Alert on UISwitch's 'ON' state

Tags: ios

I am new to this and this is my first question.
Would any one let me know whether we **can or cannot** pop a **System Alert** on UISwitch's 'ON' state.
I Know we can have custom alert but i don't want that.It is related to GPS whereby when the user switches on the switch it should give you an System Alert asking to on your GPS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's automatically displayed when the app accesses Core Location. If the user rejects it, it's displayed a second time at the next launch, then it keeps quiet and is not shown anymore.

So there is no way you could force this dialog to show again. iOS will ask the user again on the next start-up of the app.

**Edit :** If you need to show an alert for GPS you van check whether GPS is enabled or not as if userlocation is nil or not. if it is not nil then set your switch enabled else set disbled.

```
MKUserLocation *userLocation = mapView.userLocation;


if (!userLocation.location) 
{
 // Show an alert here to turn on Location service
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Location Service Disabled" 
                                                    message:@"To re-enable, please go to Settings and turn on Location Service for this app." 
                                                   delegate:nil 
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

So user can enable GPS in settings directly.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: @ Nishant Tyagi : I got your point but what i want to do is when the user click's the Switch to 'On', it should, then, give you an ALERT asking to ON your GPS. If the user clicks Yes it should On GPS else it should make the Switch back to 'Off' state.Is this achievable ???

Comment: No you can not do this. There is no way to show alert forcibly.

Comment: @ Nishant Tyagi:Can we not maintain the state of Switch in ViewDidLoad,and check if it si ON,May be invoke a System ALert for GPS... ???

Comment: you can show an alert to user to enable by checking Location service state. This way user will manually enable GPS through settings. Check my edited answer.

Comment: Nishant Tyagi : Would You PLease Elaborate your answer a bit more.

Comment: I am saying as there is no way for a user to show default alert , so you can show an alert manually and pass a message there to enable location service. So it will intimate user to enable location service if he has not already enabled.